# Sequence Prediction using Conditional Probability with Bayes rule

Tags: bayes-theorem

Let's assume we have four sequences in a dataset:
$$A \rightarrow  B$$
$$A \rightarrow  G \rightarrow M$$
$$R \rightarrow  G$$
$$B \rightarrow C \rightarrow   G \rightarrow M$$

Now, we have a new sub-sequence and we want to predict the next items in the sequence based on the prior four sequences.
Given that we saw the item $A$, I want to calculate the probability to see the sub-sequence $G\rightarrow M$ next. How should I use Bayes rule in order to calculate this probability?

I thought to use it this way:
$$P(G\rightarrow M|A)=\frac{P(G\rightarrow M)*P(A|G\rightarrow M)}{P(A)}= \frac{\frac{2}{4}*\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{2}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Explanation:

$P(G\rightarrow M)=\frac{2}{4}$ - $G\rightarrow M$ appears in two sequences out of four sequences in the dataset.

$P(A)=\frac{2}{4}$ - A appears in two sequences out of four sequences in the dataset.

$P(A|G)=\frac{1}{2}$ - Out of two appearances of $G\rightarrow M$, we have only one sub-sequences of $A \rightarrow  G \rightarrow M$ in the dataset.

Is that make sense?
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. a) I'm not sure you're using the terms "sequence" and "sub-sequence" consistently. As far as I can tell, you seem to be using "sequence" both for the four patterns at the top and for strings in which they occur, and "subsequence" for parts of the four patterns. b) $P(A\mid G)$ comes out of nowhere. It seems that you intended to refer to $P(A\mid G\to M)$ instead. c) If $A$ appears in two sequences out of four, that would suggest a probability of $\frac12$, not $\frac34$. I suspect there are further issues, but that might become clearer if you resolve these.

Comment: my comment below in an "answer" (not a proposed answer but I wanted to include graphics in my comment)

Comment: The way the problem is (vaguely) described, I can't see the answer as anything other than $1/2$ (assuming each sequence is equally likely).
If you saw item $A$ , then your possibilities are $AB$ or $AGM$.

Answer (score 0):

this is a comment, not an answer .... wanted to added graphics to discuss the problem

---

below is a "state machine" drawing ... 
[image]